# SSD is detected under Win8 and in BIOS SATA Config but not in boot menu

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, boot, ssd, bios

I've got the following issue: My new SSD I put in my Asus N56VJ for the CD drive is detected and working under Win8. In the BIOS menu under SATA-Configuration it's listed as well.

But it is not listed as a bootable device. I only see my USB CD drive and two times the Windows Boot manager pointing to the same device (I guess my HDD).

Any ideas what I can do about it? BIOS is up-to-date.

I only play around in the BIOS because Windows Installer is telling me that I can't install Win7 on the SSD because it's not bootable and when I just try it I get an error on Bootup about a wrong/damaged startup file...

**Edit:**

When I try to install Windows 7 via Windows 8 (I open the CD), I get the following info when trying to select my SSD:

`Windows cannot be installed on this hard drive. The partition is a microsoft reserved (msr) partition`

Any ideas why or how I can fix this? Is this related to my issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using GPT or MBR? If you are using MBR, is the partition you want to boot from marked as *active' ?

Comment: where can I check this or change it?

Comment: Not sure under windows 8. Assuming it is the same as windows 7: Boot winPE (aka boot the windows installation DVD), go to the command line (Shift-F10) and start `diskpart`. You want to `list disk`, then `select disk #` (replace # with the correct disk number) and then `list partition`.  It will show a table, which might show an `*` in the column GTP. If it does not have an asterix check the partitions with `list partitions` and 'list volume`. The latter has a column *info* which can show the flag *boot*.

Comment: You have a ASUS board so this test should work.  Turn the computer on and start hitting F8 and you should get a boot menu.  Does your SSD appear on this list? As seen on page A-4 in the ASUS manual I downloaded.  Select hard drive BBS priority and set the hard drive there.

Comment: I get the list via `Esc` and no, just the same options like in the BIOS menu