# Install Windows 7 on Asus Laptop with additional SSD not working

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, boot, ssd

I have an Asus N56VJ and removed the CD drive and put in an additional SSD.

The SSD is recognized under Windows 8 and working.

I tried the following to install Win7 on the SSD (I don't want Win8 at all):

- Install Win7 via Computer -> CD startup. The installer tells me that I can't install on my SSD because of this: `Windows cannot be installed on this hard drive. The partition is a microsoft reserved (msr) partition`. If I ignore this, the installer does something but when rebooting I get an ugly error about some damaged/missing file and problems with booting...
- I tried around various things and I get my external USB CD drive two times in my bootup list. If I take the `UEFI` these two bars show up telling me that Windows is copying files (black/white screen). Then the Windows 7 startscreen shows up but freezes with an ugly grapfical error.
- Taking the not-UEFI CD drive (its the same) I end up in the installer menu. But there I'm forced to select a missing USB driver. I found some posts telling me to switch the USB ports from the drive but nothing worked... So I can proceed here as well.

Furthermore the SSD is not a option for booting like I [wrote here](https://superuser.com/q/627742/138877)...

Does anyone has an idea left what I could try?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 64bits installation via USB asks for drivers](http://superuser.com/questions/401532/windows-7-64bits-installation-via-usb-asks-for-drivers)

Comment: hm, stupid question but where do I get USB 3.0 drivers? Just general ones?

Comment: You can download them directly from ASUS, for your particular laptop and OS.  I noticed [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/615408/6887) from that linked question, where this person solved the issue at hand with an almost identical laptop to yours.

Comment: I tried the Chipset drivers but none of them works... they are all rejected by the Windows installation... any ideas which one in particular?